# Display 2D array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, command-line

I have a 2 dimensional array

```
NSInteger arr [3][3] = {{0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0}};
```

and I'm trying to display it in Xcode's command line.  I have:

```
NSLog(@"%d", arr);
```

but it doesn't work. Why and what do I need to use?

Comment: It simple as you do in *C/C++*. Write loop for display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSDictionary` like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict= @{@0:@[@0,@0,@0],
                       @1:@[@0,@0,@0],
                          @2:@[@0,@0,@0]};
```

And then, print it like this

```
NSLog(@"%d",[[dict objectForKey:@1][0] intValue];)
```

Let me explain you in detail what exactly is happening here..
Instead of creating a 2 dimensional array, you are creating a NSDictionary with key value pair.

Here you are setting `NSArray` type values for `NSNumber` type keys. So you have 3 keys here.. "@0,@1 & @2". For each you are assigning an `NSArray` object as value. which is `@[@0,@0,@0]` each.

at time of printing value, first you are getting the exact NSArray from its key by using `[dict objectForKey:@1]`. Then to get 0th element of array, you are using `[dict objectForKey:@1][0]`.

As each element of `NSArray` is `NSNumber` here, you are getting intValue of the object & simply printing it.

To print complete array object, use this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[dict description]);
```

**Update:**

Do this if you insist using NSInteger:

```
NSInteger arr [3][3] = {{0, 3, 0},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0}};
NSLog(@"{");
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"{");
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d, ",arr[i][j]);
        }
        NSLog(@"},");
    }
    NSLog(@"}");
```

Comment: I need to use NSInteger, not NSDictionary

Comment: I follow what you are doing, but I need to create a 2D array, not an NSDictionary.  So if (@"%d", ...) prints a Dictionary, what code prints an NSInteger array [][]?

Answer (score 1):

`NSLog` doesn't know how to display a C array the way you want. 
You will need **two nested for loops** to do this. 
The outer loop iterates the first dimension indexes. 
The inner loop iterates the second dimension indexes. 
You probably want to create an `NSMutableString` in the outer loop and add to it with each iteration of the inner loop using `stringWithFormat:` then you can print that string with `NSLog` after the inner loop ( in the outer loop )

You could also create a main `NSMutableString` outside the outer loop and add each string to it after the inner loop the log it after the outer loop.

```
NSInteger idx1 = 3;
NSInteger idx2 = 3;
NSInteger arr [idx1][idx2] = {{0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0}};


NSMutableString *finalString = [NSMutableString new];

for ( NSInteger i = 0; i < idx1; ++i) {
   NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString new];
   for ( NSInteger j = 0; j < idx2; ++j) {
       [temp appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%ld]", arr[i][j] ]];
   }
   [temp appendString: @"\n"];
   [finalString appendString:temp];
}

NSLog(@"%@", finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently displaying a single integer. You need to display the entire object.